# Any known causes for "illegal hardware instruction rails server" errors in Rails 3.1 RC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm not sure what's causing this error - and am not sure how to debug the issue.  Does anyone have any pointers for advice on the error "illegal hardware instruction  rails server" when running a Rails 3.1 app?

thanks in advance,
dan

UPDATE:

The error is always reproducible and only occurs in a project I'm trying to upgrade from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1 (RC1)

I didn't see anything in the logs - except for a bunch of warnings:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <class:Entity> at .../app/models/entity.rb:3)
```

The warnings are from the use of a gem called acts_as_audited.  If I comment that out... it works.  I didn't think a warning would cause a rails to report a hardware error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the error reproducible? If yes, then you may suspect the software. Maybe some library or ruby itself has been recently upgraded?

In any case it would be a good idea to check the machine against memory errors and disk problems. Maybe there is some info in the system logs?

You haven't said what system you are on, but in any case - ensure the hardware is OK, ensure the basic system is OK, check whether your code has no infinite loops or similar errors, check whether the error still exists on different versions of Rails or ruby.

That's for start. :)

Comment: I've stumbled into this bug this morning too. The cause is there's a recursive call to update active record. silly me.

Answer (score 7):

Got the same error, but I've solved it. My problem was caused by a v8 engine installed from HomeBrew. Simply remove it solves the issue.

Your situation may be different, I offer you a good way to inspect it. 
When your rails server crashed, Mac OS X will save a crash report as

`~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ruby_*.crash`

Then you can check this file, and find the crashed thread descriptions. On my system, it reports:

`Thread 4 Crashed: 
0   libv8.dylib                     0x00000001030a08f8 v8::internal::HandleScope::DeleteExtensions(v8::internal::Isolate*) + 24`

Comment: Thanks, looking at the DiagnosticReports helped me.  For me though I needed to `brew install v8` then `gem uninstall libv8` `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' -- --with-system-v8` to solve the crashing libv8 issue when running `rails s`